# How do I change how fast the cursor hides on VLC in full screen mode?

Tags: vlc-media-player

When playing videos in full screen mode on VLC, I find that the mouse takes too long to hide (the control panel hides quickly enough, but the mouse lingers around for much longer).

How do i control how fast the cursor hides?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change this, its just buried in VLC's hundreds of configuration options.  Open up the VLC preferences dialog (Tools->Preferences) then:

1. Click on the Show All radio button in the bottom left corner.
2. Select the "Video" category.
3. Update the "Hide cursor and fullscreen controller after x milliseconds" value to the desired timeout.

[image: VLC Preferences Dialog]

Comment: Ah, thats where it was. Thank you. I kept looking around the interface settings and couldn't find it there.

Comment: For some reason, my cursor never disappears at all in fullscreen (or otherwise). I had a look at the field you indicated, and it's at 1500. Any idea what my problem is?

Comment: Look at background programs in your system tray - try closing each one-by-one until the problem is solved. In my case it was Greenshot that was the culprit.